# How to aggregate data in table by month in spotfire

Tags: spotfire

So my original table is like this:

[image]

And I want to compress the table which only shows that factoryID and the month, and the max output like this:

[image]

How do I do this with spotfire in table visualization?

Answer (score 4):

To go from the top table to the bottom table:
[image]

Do these steps:

1. Create a new calculated column off of your date for mmm-yy: `Concatenate(Month([Date]),"-",right(String(Year([Date])),2))`
2. Add a pivot transformation with the following parameters:
   [image]

I created it as a new table but you do not have to.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!

Answer (score 3):

1. **Create two caculated columns**.

c_month, c_max

for c_month, use the expression: `Concatenate(Month([date]),"-",Year([date]))`

for c_max, use the expression: `Max([max]) OVER ([factory id])`

2. **Add third column called c_rank**
   expression:

`If(Rank(RowId(),"asc",[factory id])=Min(Rank(RowId(),"asc",[factory id])),True)`

*//this will create a new calculated column which will give true only for every unique value of factory id.*

3. **Add a data table to your visualization**
4. **Add data limiter**

Right click and under data --> Limit Data using expression, enter `[c_rank] = true`

4. **Create Table with limted columns**

Only add factory id, c_month and c_max to your column list.

[image]